# ComponentDidMount() not called from bundle.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

From what I understand, server-side rendering doesn't complete the React lifecycle, it just stops at `render()` so `componentDidMount()` is not called. To get the whole life cycle you need to bundle up your page using some tool like webpack and inclue the bundled file in your page somehow, usually as a `<script>`.

I'm trying to do that and have successfully gotten my `bundle.js` inside my webpage, but I still don't see any `console.log()`'s that I have set in my components' `componentDidMount()`.

The server-side rendering is coming back correctly because my page has all the static content, but none of the behavior that I want defined in my components is happening.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './views/Index.jsx'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(jsx|js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/ , use: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

`./views/Index.jsx` points to my main template file which looks like this:

**Index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './Layout.jsx';
import Cube from './components/Cube/Cube.jsx';

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Layout title={this.props.title}>
            <Cube />
        </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Where `Layout.jsx` is where I'm including the `<script src="/public/bundle.js">`:

**Layout.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>{this.props.title}</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/bundle.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          {this.props.children}
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

And finally, in my Cube.jsx I have a `componentDidMount()` with a `console.log()`:

**Cube.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class Cube extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("SUHHH");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Cube;
```

Can anybody please help me understand why in neither my chrome console nor my pm2 logs I'm seeing any signs of my `componentDidMount()` being executed?

Here is my app if that helps: https://github.com/MarksCode/PersonalWebsite

Thanks!

Comment: did you `ReactDOM.render` your component?

Comment: Sorry for the noobie question, where/how would I do that?

Comment: you need to create a regular html file with div then give it id then insert your react component file on that html page. On your root component `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` after that `ReactDOM.render(<YourRootComponent/>, document.querySelector('#your-div-id'));`

Comment: How would that fit in the flow of how I'm doing my server-side rendering? I'm having trouble picturing where I would put the above code.

Comment: @MarksCode i suggest you try to read the react [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html), also if you want server side rendering check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html)